# How to Record Screen of specific View using surfaceview?

Tags: android

Have a screen with two buttons and `surfaceview` and i want to record screen only of `surfaceview` except those two button.

This is the link that I follow.

Through this `api` I can record the whole screen but not only `surfaceview`.

or any idea in which I can removes button and record the screen

please give me some idea or helping material.

Comment: i use media projection api

Comment: http://www.truiton.com/2015/05/capture-record-android-screen-using-mediaprojection-apis/